# Rails still using mysql2 even though current environment is using sqlite3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I got an application with a `staging` and a `production` server. `staging` has to run a sqlite3 database and `production` a mysql database, because `staging` can't install the `mysql2` gem.

This is the complete `database.yml` on staging:

```
staging:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/staging.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

However, the Gemfile has both gems: `mysql2` and `sqlite3` and get this when deploying:

```
** [out :: example.org] rake aborted!
** [out :: example.org] Incorrect MySQL client library version! This gem was compiled for 5.6.21 but the client library is 5.1.61.
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2/mysql2.so
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/mysql2-0.3.16/lib/mysql2.rb:8
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/application1/releases/20150918175707/config/application.rb:13
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/application1/releases/20150918175707/Rakefile:5:in `require'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/application1/releases/20150918175707/Rakefile:5
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/rake_module.rb:25:in `load_rakefile'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:589:in `raw_load_rakefile'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:89:in `load_rakefile'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:88:in `load_rakefile'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:72:in `run'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:160:in `standard_exception_handling'
** [out :: example.org] /path/to/my/app/.gem/ruby/1.8/gems/rake-10.0.4/lib/rake/application.rb:70:in `run'
```

How and why is Rails trying to use `mysql` when there's only `sqlite3` in the `database.yml`?

Comment: Can you update mysql version on the server?

Comment: No, unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

You need to update your Gemfile like this

```
group :staging do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end
group :production do
  gem 'mysql'
end
```

Basically you need to tell your Gemfile which gem to use for which environment, if you dont they will be installed for all environments even if you dont use them in code.

Do this in your gem file

```
if File.dirname(__FILE__).to_s.include?('part_of_production_directory_path')
  gem 'mysql'
else File.dirname(__FILE__).to_s.include?('part_of_staging_directory_path')
 gem 'sqlite3'
end
```

Comment: Oh, yes I tried that too but the problem is, the apps run on a crappy managed server where I can only use production as an environment. Don't ask me why but it is what it is... any other idea? :(

Comment: try this **bundle install --without mysql**